# Create a column family using pycassa

Tags: python, cassandra, pycassa

How does one create a column family programmatically using pycassa? I couldn't find it in the docs. It seems that all of the column family operations deal with existing column families.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a column family programmatically in pycassa, I guess below example is what you are looking for.

```
 validators = {'full_name': UTF8_TYPE,
              'email': UTF8_TYPE,
              'state': UTF8_TYPE,
              'gender': UTF8_TYPE,
              'birth_year': LONG_TYPE}
 sys.create_column_family('TestKeyspace', 'TestCF', super=False,
              comparator_type=UTF8Type,
              key_validation_class=UTF8Type, 
              column_validation_classes=validators)
```